# Why is my DAPC giving me less clusters when I use more PCs?

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I know this is not a coding question, but I don't know where else to ask.

I'm performing a DAPC in R, using the adegenet package. I only have 84 individuals, and I'm using a gening object with about 5000 SNPs to try and see if there's genetic diference between sample sites (4). I'm using the grp function to find how many clusters I should use. However, when I run de grp function, if I choose to keep 84 PCs the best BIC indicates 2 clusters. If I choose to keep 28 PCs, the BIC indicates 4 clusters. Why does this happen? If I'm using more PC's and adding more information shouldn't that give me more clusters?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a better suited question for [su] or, if done in a professional environment (given that you have several clusters), on [sf]

Comment: Thank you for your help!